# Get number of folders in root of ZipFile

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, zip

I'm trying to check if my zip is *valid*.

The zip file looks like this (only one root folder with content):

```
zip-root
`-- folder1
    |-- folder1
    |-- folder2
    |-- folder3
    |-- folder4
    `-- folder5
```

The structure of the zip file is considered *invalid* if

- root of zip contains more than one **folder**

I tried the following:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(ZipFilePath))
{
    rootArchiveFolder = archive.Entries.Count();        
}
```

but this returns the count of all folders, whereas I'm only interested in the *root-folder-count*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder is recognised with its `FullName` ending with slash (`/`).
So, in your case, you can get list of folders inside the root of archive like this:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(ZipFilePath)
{
    var listOfZipFolders = archive.Entries.Where(x => x.FullName.EndsWith("/")).ToList();
    int foldersCount = archive.Entries.Count(x => x.FullName.EndsWith("/"));
}
```

or, LINQless version:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(ZipFilePath))
{
    List<ZipArchiveEntry> listOfZipFolders = new List<ZipArchiveEntry>();
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith("/"))
            listOfZipFolders.Add(entry);
    }
    int foldersCount = listOfZipFolders.Count;
}
```

**EDIT**: previous code examples work only with empty folders.

this will find a list of root folders (empty, not empty or having subfolders)

```
var folders = archive.Entries
    .Where
        (x => x.FullName.Split('/').Length > 1 || 
           x.FullName.EndsWith("/")
        )
    .Select(f => f.FullName.Split('/')`[0])
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

var foldersCount = archive.Entries
    .Where
        (x => x.FullName.Split('/').Length > 1 || 
           x.FullName.EndsWith("/")
        )
    .Select(f => f.FullName.Split('/')`[0])
    .Distinct()
    .Count()
```

Comment: It still does not work: I have valid archive which contain one root folder with 5 folders inside. `foldersCount ` = 6, not one

Comment: You should count items which end with / and only contain one /

Comment: Looks like my code works only with empty folders. I've added version that should work with all scenarios (one or more folders in root containing __n__ folders and/or files).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the entries list is flat. But with this filter, you should be able to get the root-folder-count.

```
int foldersCount;
using (var zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(file))
{
    foldersCount = zip.Entries.Count(e => e.FullName.Split('/').Length == 3 && e.FullName.EndsWith("/"));
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this won't work when there are two root folders, one empty and other with files and subfolders.

Comment: @Nino I tested it with two folders in root (one empty, one with subfolders and files). It worked.

Comment: remove Count and put Where and so you'll that you have false positive. `.FullName.Split('/').Length == 3` will find subfolder in second level. Namely, `(root) folder1/folder1/` in Sveta's example.

Comment: @Nino no it won't because empty level-two-folders will return split-length 4.. that's because empty level-two-folders end with a forward slash

Comment: Second level folder is written as folder1/folder2/. Split will return array with three elements: "folder1", "folder2" and "" (empty string). I think your code will work if `.Length == 2`. That way it works and it's simplier than my version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110509/discussion-between-soumer-and-nino).

Comment: this doesn't work if there are no files in the root or root directory and only directories. root/folder1, root/folder2, root/folder1/file